# how to set multiple infowindows in google maps but with this particular javascript method

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, csv, google-maps-api-3

I looked all over and even though there are tons of instructions and techniques and javascript code everywhere on how to do this, I can't use any of them, because it will require rewriting all my javascript and php. Is there code for info windows I can drop into this method i am using?

I am reading a csv file and parsing the data with this library (https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php), then I'm putting markers on the map with this icon library (https://github.com/scottdejonge/map-icons). now I need to add info window for each marker (where it displays the first column data of csv file) and I don't know how to go about it. I don't mean i don't know the php variable to use, that part is easy. what I mean is I don't know what infowindow javascript to use.

I am going to paste whole html page plus the contents of the csv file.

```
<?php
# include parseCSV class.
require_once('../parsecsv.lib.php');
# create new parseCSV object.
$csv = new parseCSV();
# Parse 'test.csv' using automatic delimiter detection...
$csv->auto('test.csv');
# ...or if you know the delimiter, set the delimiter character
# if its not the default comma...
// $csv->delimiter = "\t";   # tab delimited
# ...and then use the parse() function.
// $csv->parse('test.csv');
# Output result.
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($csv->data);
//echo "</pre>";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Map Icons Example</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<!-- Google Maps -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<!-- Map Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dist/css/map-icons.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/js/map-icons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialise() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    // Center
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46834, 153.02365);
    // Map Options      
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: center,
        scrollwheel: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [
            {stylers: [{ visibility: 'simplified' }]},
            {elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]}
        ]
    };
    // Create the Map
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    <?php
    $i=1;
    $extendthis = "";
    foreach ($csv->data as $key => $row):
    // We define our address
    $fulladdress = $row['address'].",".$row['city'].",".$row['state'].",".$row['zip'];
    $marker = $row['marker'];
    $icon = $row['icon'];
    $fillcolor = $row['fillcolor'];
    //if no marker or icon or fillcolor is set, use default ones...
    if ($marker=="") {
        $marker = "MAP_PIN";
    }
    if ($icon=="") {
        $icon = "";
    }
    if ($fillcolor=="") {
        $fillcolor = "6331AE";
    }
    // We get the JSON results from this request
    $geo = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($fulladdress).'');
    // We convert the JSON to an array
    $geo = json_decode($geo, true);
    // If everything is cool
    if ($geo['status'] = 'OK') {
      // We set our values
      $latitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
      $longitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    }
    echo "var Item_".$i." = new google.maps.LatLng(".$latitude.", ".$longitude.");\n";
    echo "var marker1 = new Marker({\n";
    echo "map: map,\n";
    echo "title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)',\n";
    echo "position: Item_".$i.",\n";
    echo "icon: {\n";
    echo "path: ".$marker.",\n";
    echo "fillColor: '#".$fillcolor."',\n";
    echo "fillOpacity: 1,\n";
    echo "strokeColor: '',\n";
    echo "strokeWeight: 0\n";
    echo "},\n";
    echo "map_icon_label: '<span class=\"map-icon ".$icon."\"></span>'\n";
    echo "});\n";
    $extendthis .= "bounds.extend(Item_".$i.");\n";
    $i++;
    endforeach;
    ?>
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    <?php echo $extendthis; ?>
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);
</script>
<style media="screen">
html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#map-canvas {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
table { background-color: #BBB; }
th { background-color: #EEE; }
td { background-color: #FFF; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($csv->titles as $value): ?>
        <th><?php echo $value; ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($csv->data as $key => $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($row as $value): ?>
        <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

test.csv:

```
name,address,city,state,zip,marker,icon,fillcolor
one,7505 3rd Street,Schenectady,NY,12302,,,
two,6422 Route 29,Bear,DE,19701,MAP_PIN,,00CCBB
three,2858 Lakeview Drive,Venice,FL,34293,,,
four,335 Lincoln Street,Augusta,GA,30906,,,
five,3907 Cardinal Drive,San Antonio,TX,78213,SQUARE_PIN,,00CCBB
six,8560 State Street,Drexel Hill,PA,19026,,,
```

Updated version, but still not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var iw;
function initialise() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    // Center
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46834, 153.02365);
    // Map Options      
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: center,
        scrollwheel: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [
            {stylers: [{ visibility: 'simplified' }]},
            {elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]}
        ]
    };
    // Create the Map
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    <?php
    $i=1;
    $extendthis = "";
    foreach ($csv->data as $key => $row):
    $name = $row['name'];
    // We define our address
    $fulladdress = $row['address'].",".$row['city'].",".$row['state'].",".$row['zip'];
    $marker = $row['marker'];
    $icon = $row['icon'];
    $fillcolor = $row['fillcolor'];
    //if no marker or icon or fillcolor is set, use default ones...
    if ($marker=="") {
        $marker = "MAP_PIN";
    }
    if ($icon=="") {
        $icon = "";
    }
    if ($fillcolor=="") {
        $fillcolor = "6331AE";
    }
    // We get the JSON results from this request
    $geo = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($fulladdress).'');
    // We convert the JSON to an array
    $geo = json_decode($geo, true);
    // If everything is cool
    if ($geo['status'] = 'OK') {
      // We set our values
      $latitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
      $longitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    }
    echo "var Item_".$i." = new google.maps.LatLng(".$latitude.", ".$longitude.");\n";
    echo "var marker".$i." = new Marker({\n";
    echo "map: map,\n";
    //echo "title: 'your title here',\n";
    echo "content: '".$name."',\n";
    echo "position: Item_".$i.",\n";
    echo "icon: {\n";
    echo "path: ".$marker.",\n";
    echo "fillColor: '#".$fillcolor."',\n";
    echo "fillOpacity: 1,\n";
    echo "strokeColor: '',\n";
    echo "strokeWeight: 0\n";
    echo "},\n";
    echo "map_icon_label: '<span class=\"map-icon ".$icon."\"></span>'\n";
    echo "});\n";
    echo "marker".$i.".addListener('click',function(m) { iw.setContent(m.content);iw.open(map,m); });\n";
    $extendthis .= "bounds.extend(Item_".$i.");\n";
    $i++;
    endforeach;
    ?>
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    <?php echo $extendthis; ?>
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with just one infowindow:

Define a global variable to store the infowindow. In order to be used by the click event, it should be global. To do so, define it outside the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var iw;
function initialise() {
...
```

And then instantiate a new infowindow in the initialise function:

```
function initialise() {
     iw=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
     ...
```

You can add custom properties to the markers. Say, for example, "content" and set the content for the marker's infowindow there:

```
echo "var marker$i = new Marker({content:'content for current marker here',\n";
...
```

Then add a click event to the marker:

```
echo "marker$i.addListener('click',function(e) { iw.setContent(this.content);iw.open(map,this); });";
```

Comment: thanks but can't get it to work. don't know where to put the lines. trying in different spots. get this error in latest attempt, but it's from google's api file (not any of my files): TypeError: b.get is not a function

Comment: also i forgot to make marker1 into a counting var. please see updated code.

Comment: I imagined that the 1 from marker1 should change, but I wrote as your code was. Updating my answer with more details.

Comment: updated code again, and i used the dynamic variable for content (which shouldn't hurt the technique), however, still not working. the markers show fine, but clicking them do nothing except create javascript error. same one from before.

Comment: Please post the error or a link where we can try it. I didn't test the code, I wrote it just here to give you the idea.

Comment: My mistake, the argument of the click event handler is not the marker. I've updated the answer, note the change from `m` to `this` in the last code.